# My log not executed after the sqlite database transaction? why its executes before the db transaction?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am getting data from Sqlite table and storing into the  Array 'favoritesData' in react native, But problem is, db transaction executes after the Log, that means I am getting an empty array.

Any one have the solution for following code....

```
getFavorits =() => {
    favoritesData = []        
    db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT * FROM table_favorites', [],
            (tx, results) => {
                len = results.rows.length;
                console.log('Total Fav = ', len);

                if (len > 0) {

                    for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
                        favoritesData.push(results.rows.item(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    });
console.log("FAV DATA: ",favoritesData)
}
```

Comment: Because db transaction is an async operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction is async. It's not blocking so the logging will (most likely) be executed before the DB operation is done. You need to move the logging into the promise chain. Either after the transactions is done:

```
getFavorites = () => {
    favoritesData = [];
    db.transaction(tx => 
        tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT * FROM table_favorites', [],
            (tx, results) => {
                len = results.rows.length;
                console.log('Total Fav = ', len);

                for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
                    favoritesData.push(results.rows.item(i));
                }
            }
        );
    ).then(() => {
      console.log("FAV DATA: ",favoritesData)
    })
}
```

Or just log after the loop:

```
getFavorites = () => {
    favoritesData = [];
    db.transaction(tx => 
        tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT * FROM table_favorites', [],
            (tx, results) => {
                len = results.rows.length;
                console.log('Total Fav = ', len);

                for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
                    favoritesData.push(results.rows.item(i));
                }
                console.log("FAV DATA: ",favoritesData)
            }
        );
    )
}
```

Also the if(len > 0) is not needed as the loop takes care of that.

Comment: in first eg. throwing compile time run time error  [TypeError: undefined is not an object (near '...}).then(function () {...')]

Comment: @Jagdish Sounds like db.transaction and/or tx.executeSql might ne callback based. In that case you need to promisify them or stick to the second example.